# Pass JavaScript variables into PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I want to pass JavaScript variables into PHP. I know this maybe impossible, so I try to use `window.location.href` to help me that PHP get JS variables, but question is I don't want it refresh when I clicked the video.

How can I do to make it don't refresh after I click video?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>UerAnalysis</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>-->
</head>

<body>
    <video id="video" src="Source/Maroon 5 - Sugar.mp4" width="500px" height="400px"  onplay="startTime()" onpause="endTime()" controls>
        <source src="Source/Maroon 5 - Sugar.mp4">
    </video>
    <br>
    <span id="TimeArea_start"></span>
    <span id="TimeArea_end"></span>
    <?php 
        echo ('<script src="js/script.js"></script>');
     ?>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("video");

function startTime() {
    console.log("StarTime:" + vid.currentTime)
    var StarTime = document.getElementById("TimeArea_start").innerHTML; 
    var EndTime = document.getElementById("TimeArea_end").innerHTML; 

    if (StarTime < EndTime) {
        console.log("StarTime:" + StarTime + "EndTime:" + EndTime + "," + "It" + "s" + " Success!!");
    }
    var x = document.getElementById("TimeArea_start").innerHTML = vid.currentTime;
    return window.location.href = "index2.php?vid=" + x;
}

function endTime() {
    console.log("EndTime:" + vid.currentTime)
    return document.getElementById("TimeArea_end").innerHTML = vid.currentTime
};
```

Comment: Your goal is not very clear. You want your JS to notify your server that the video was started? That way you can store that in a database and get stats? If so, you might want to search "Ajax". It sends requests to your server without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to pass something into a PHP, without expecting any response, you can use jQuery's AJAX [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) function for that: (I can see you have jQuery loaded in your page anyway)

```
function startTime() {
    console.log("StarTime:" + vid.currentTime)
    var StarTime = document.getElementById("TimeArea_start").innerHTML; 
    var EndTime = document.getElementById("TimeArea_end").innerHTML; 

    if (StarTime < EndTime) {
        console.log("StarTime:" + StarTime + "EndTime:" + EndTime + "," + "It" + "s" + " Success!!");
    }
    var x = document.getElementById("TimeArea_start").innerHTML = vid.currentTime;
    jQuery.get("index2.php?vid=" + x);
}
```

This will not reload your page. The index.php fill be called completely in the background.

Comment: _"without expecting any response"_, **or** actually expecting a response. `$.get()` accepts a `success` callback.

Comment: Correct. He does not seem to require any response, though.

Comment: Thanks it work!!Just a little bug need to fix on my code.

Answer (score 0):

Js is client script. you can not pass javascript variables into php. But you can using ajax or redirect url to submit data to server. In your case you can use ajax to post data to sever.

```
 return window.location.href = "index2.php?vid=" + x;
```

you can replace by ajax code. Hope that useful for you.